# execute immediate sql with variables for stats

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to create some stats from the meta data of the primary key from each table in oracle. I get error message (see below). My script is as follows:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_owner            VARCHAR2(40);
    v_table_name       VARCHAR2(40);
    v_column_name      VARCHAR2(40);
    v_count_rows       NUMBER;
    v_count_real_rows  NUMBER;
    v_count_rows_diff  NUMBER;
    v_rn_tables        NUMBER;
    v_count_tables     NUMBER;
    v_max_primary_key  NUMBER;
    sql_stmt           VARCHAR2(32767);
    CURSOR get_tables IS
    SELECT
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,
        cols.column_name,
        nvl(num_rows, - 1)      AS count_rows,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
             ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                       AS rn_tables,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name)
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
            -- ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                       AS count_tables
    FROM
        all_constraints   cons,
        all_cons_columns  cols,
        all_tables        tab
    WHERE
            cols.table_name = tab.table_name
        AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
        AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
        AND cons.owner = cols.owner
        AND tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'
        AND cols.position = 1
    ORDER BY
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name;

BEGIN
    OPEN get_tables;
    LOOP
        FETCH get_tables INTO
            v_owner,
            v_table_name,
            v_column_name,
            v_count_real_rows,
            v_rn_tables,
            v_count_tables;
        EXIT WHEN get_tables%notfound;
         -- dbms_output.put_line('Tabelle ' || v_owner ||' ' || v_table_name||' ' || v_column_name||' ' || v_count_real_rows  ); 

        sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,max('||v_column_name||') as max_primary_key FROM '
                    || v_owner
                    || '.'
                    || v_table_name
                    ;
     --   dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt
        INTO v_count_rows,v_max_primary_key
        ;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_rn_tables ||' out of '||v_count_tables ||' '||v_owner
                                 || '.'
                                 || v_table_name
                                 || ': '
                                 || v_count_rows
                                 || ': '
                                 || v_count_real_rows
                                 || ': '
                                 || v_count_rows_diff);


    END LOOP;

    CLOSE get_tables;
END;
```

The error is:

```
    ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 63
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Where could be the problem? If I run it without v_max_primary_key it works.

Answer (score 1):

The column you are trying to select the maximum value of the primary key is not a `NUMBER` column so Oracle is implicitly trying to convert the value from whatever data-type it is to a number and that fails.

When I run your query in a fiddle the output is:

```
1 out of 3 CTXSYS.DR$OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE: 502: 502: 
2 out of 3 CTXSYS.DR$THS: 0: 0: 
3 out of 3 CTXSYS.DR$THS_PHRASE: 0: 0: 
1 out of 1 FIDDLE_KQOAUBPRJBOCOJMYPOKT.TEST: 1: -1: 
1 out of 35 MDSYS.NTV2_XML_DATA: 0: 0: 
2 out of 35 MDSYS.OGIS_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS: 0: 0: 

ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 60
```

Whichever table is being read next does not have a numeric primary key.

---

Apart from that:

- You are trying to query all the tables of all the users in the database; you probably want to restrict the query to a whitelist of specific users.
- You join on `cons.owner = cols.owner` but you do not join on `cols.owner = tab.owner`.
- Your dynamic query will fail if any of the identifiers should be quoted.

If you create the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES ('1');
```

Then (updating the join conditions and limiting the query to the current user):

```sql
DECLARE
    v_owner            VARCHAR2(40);
    v_table_name       VARCHAR2(40);
    v_column_name      VARCHAR2(40);
    v_count_rows       NUMBER;
    v_count_real_rows  NUMBER;
    v_count_rows_diff  NUMBER;
    v_rn_tables        NUMBER;
    v_count_tables     NUMBER;
    v_max_primary_key  NUMBER;
    sql_stmt           VARCHAR2(32767);
    CURSOR get_tables IS
    SELECT
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,
        cols.column_name,
        nvl(num_rows, - 1)      AS count_rows,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
             ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                       AS rn_tables,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name)
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
            -- ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                       AS count_tables
    FROM all_constraints   cons
         INNER JOIN all_cons_columns  cols
         ON (    cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
             AND cons.owner = cols.owner)
         INNER JOIN all_tables        tab
         ON (    cols.table_name = tab.table_name
             AND cols.owner      = tab.owner)
    WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P'
    AND   tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'
    AND   cols.position = 1
    AND   tab.owner = USER
    ORDER BY
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name;

BEGIN
    OPEN get_tables;
    LOOP
        FETCH get_tables INTO
            v_owner,
            v_table_name,
            v_column_name,
            v_count_real_rows,
            v_rn_tables,
            v_count_tables;
        EXIT WHEN get_tables%notfound;
         -- dbms_output.put_line('Tabelle ' || v_owner ||' ' || v_table_name||' ' || v_column_name||' ' || v_count_real_rows  ); 

        sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,max('||DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_column_name, FALSE)||') as max_primary_key FROM '
                    || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_owner, FALSE)
                    || '.'
                    || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_table_name, FALSE)
                    ;
     --   dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt
        INTO v_count_rows,v_max_primary_key
        ;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_rn_tables ||' out of '||v_count_tables ||' '||v_owner
                                 || '.'
                                 || v_table_name
                                 || ': '
                                 || v_count_rows
                                 || ': '
                                 || v_count_real_rows
                                 || ': '
                                 || v_count_rows_diff);


    END LOOP;

    CLOSE get_tables;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
1 out of 1 FIDDLE_KQOAUBPRJBOCOJMYPOKT.TEST: 1: -1:
```

If a value that cannot be converted to a number is added:

```
INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES ('A');
```

Then the output is:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 60
```

Either:

- Filter your query to only `NUMBER` columns; or
- Don't try and get the value as a `NUMBER` when the data is not numeric. Try `v_max_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);` (although that may still fail for some data-types that do not have an implicit conversion to a string).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7cfrneqU)

Comment: DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_column_name, FALSE) and VARCHAR2(4000) helped to enable the script, thanks!