# escape problem within execute immediate with REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is a followup from previous question:
[execute immediate sql with variables for stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77919692/execute-immediate-sql-with-variables-for-stats/77919833#comment137381045_77919833)

I have added a new column with sum operation to above execute immediate sql. The problem with it is, that both characters and numbers can appear. So I needed to include a case when condition with REGEXP_LIKE, but now I have a problem with escape special characters. Quoting string literal technique does not work either:

a)

```
    sql_stmt := q'[
            SELECT
      COUNT(*)                                                      AS count_rows,
      MAX(dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false))           AS max_primary_key,
      MIN(dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false))           AS min_primary_key,
      SUM(
          CASE
              WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(v_column_name, '^(\+|-)?[0-9]*((.)?[0-9])[0-9]*$') THEN
                  to_number(v_column_name)
              ELSE
                  0
          END
      )                                                             AS sum_primary_key
  FROM
      dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_owner, false).dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_table_name, false)
        ]';
```

---

b)

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,max('
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || ') as max_primary_key,min('
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || ') as min_primary_key, SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || '',^(\+|-)?[0-9]*((.)?[0-9])[0-9]*$'') THEN  to_number('
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || ')  ELSE    0        END    )    as sum_primary_key FROM '
                || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_owner, FALSE)
                || '.'
                || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_table_name, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use it like this one?

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,max('
            || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
            || q'[) as max_primary_key,min(]'
            || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
            || q'[) as min_primary_key, SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(]'
            || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
            || q'[,:regExp) THEN  to_number(]'
            || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
            || q'[)  ELSE    0        END    )    as sum_primary_key FROM ]'
            || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_owner, FALSE)
            || '.'
            || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_table_name, FALSE);
execute immediate sql_stmt INTO ... USING '^(\+|-)?[0-9]*((.)?[0-9])[0-9]*$';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the quotes in the correct places:

```sql
sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,'
                || 'max(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false) || ') as max_primary_key, '
                || 'min(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false) || ') as min_primary_key, '
                || 'SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                         || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                         || ',''^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$'') '
                         || 'THEN to_number(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false) || ') '
                         || 'ELSE 0 '
                         || 'END'
                || ') as sum_primary_key '
           || 'FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_owner, FALSE)
                     || '.'
                     || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_table_name, FALSE);
```

*(and in the regular expression `.` matches any character, `\.` matches only the decimal point and you can simplify the expression.)*

Which would give you:

```sql
DECLARE
    v_owner            VARCHAR2(40);
    v_table_name       VARCHAR2(40);
    v_column_name      VARCHAR2(40);
    v_count_rows       NUMBER;
    v_count_real_rows  NUMBER;
    v_count_rows_diff  NUMBER;
    v_rn_tables        NUMBER;
    v_count_tables     NUMBER;
    v_min_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_max_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_sum_primary_key  NUMBER;
    sql_stmt           VARCHAR2(32767);
    CURSOR get_tables IS
    SELECT
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,
        cols.column_name,
        nvl(num_rows, - 1)      AS count_rows,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
             ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                       AS rn_tables,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name)
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
            -- ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                       AS count_tables
    FROM all_constraints   cons
         INNER JOIN all_cons_columns  cols
         ON (    cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
             AND cons.owner = cols.owner)
         INNER JOIN all_tables        tab
         ON (    cols.table_name = tab.table_name
             AND cols.owner      = tab.owner)
    WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P'
    AND   tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'
    AND   cols.position = 1
    AND   tab.owner = USER
    ORDER BY
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name;

BEGIN
    OPEN get_tables;
    LOOP
        FETCH get_tables INTO
            v_owner,
            v_table_name,
            v_column_name,
            v_count_real_rows,
            v_rn_tables,
            v_count_tables;
        EXIT WHEN get_tables%notfound;
         -- dbms_output.put_line('Tabelle ' || v_owner ||' ' || v_table_name||' ' || v_column_name||' ' || v_count_real_rows  ); 

        sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,'
                || 'max(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false) || ') as max_primary_key, '
                || 'min(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false) || ') as min_primary_key, '
                || 'SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                         || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                         || ',''^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$'') '
                         || 'THEN to_number(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false) || ') '
                         || 'ELSE 0 '
                         || 'END'
                || ') as sum_primary_key '
           || 'FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_owner, FALSE)
                      || '.'
                      || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_table_name, FALSE);
     --   dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt
        INTO v_count_rows, v_min_primary_key, v_max_primary_key, v_sum_primary_key;
        dbms_output.put_line(
           v_rn_tables ||' out of '||v_count_tables ||' '||v_owner
           || '.'
           || v_table_name
           || ': '
           || v_count_rows
           || ': '
           || v_count_real_rows
           || ': '
           || v_count_rows_diff
           || ': ('
           || v_min_primary_key
           || ', '
           || v_max_primary_key
           || ', '
           || v_sum_primary_key
           || ')'
        );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE get_tables;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BaOKqWOB)

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine the q-quote syntax with the concatenation - use it for every string that has quotes in it:

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,max('
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || q'[) as max_primary_key,min(]'
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || q'[) as min_primary_key, SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(]'
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || q'[,'^(\+|-)?[0-9]*((.)?[0-9])[0-9]*$') THEN  to_number(]'
                || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_column_name, false)
                || q'[)  ELSE    0        END    )    as sum_primary_key FROM ]'
                || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_owner, FALSE)
                || '.'
                || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_table_name, FALSE);
```