# calculate the results from 2 cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is a followup from another question: [escape problem within execute immediate with REGEXP_LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926748/escape-problem-within-execute-immediate-with-regexp-like/77926997#77926997)

Now I want to compare the results from 2 different cursors line by line. My loop does not work correctly and I get cartesian product, so each line of the one cursor is joined to all results from the other cursor one after another.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    v_count_rows_diff  NUMBER;
---------VARIABLES--------ORA1--------------------------
    v_1_owner            VARCHAR2(40);
    v_1_table_name       VARCHAR2(40);
    v_1_column_name      VARCHAR2(40);
    v_1_count_rows       NUMBER;
   -- v_1_count_real_rows  NUMBER;
    v_1_rn_tables        NUMBER;
    v_1_count_tables     NUMBER;
    v_1_max_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_1_min_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_1_sum_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    sql_stmt_1           VARCHAR2(32767);
---------VARIABLES---------ORA2----------------------
    v_2_owner            VARCHAR2(40);
    v_2_table_name       VARCHAR2(40);
    v_2_column_name      VARCHAR2(40);
    v_2_count_rows       NUMBER;
   -- v_2_count_real_rows  NUMBER;
    v_2_rn_tables        NUMBER;
    v_2_count_tables     NUMBER;
    v_2_max_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_2_min_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_2_sum_primary_key  VARCHAR2(4000);
    sql_stmt_2           VARCHAR2(32767);
-------------CURSOR----ORA1--------------------------
    CURSOR get_tables_1 IS
SELECT
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,
        cols.column_name as primary_key,
   --        case tab_col.data_type when 'NUMBER' THEN 'numerical' else 'not' end as data_type,
    --    nvl(num_rows, - 1)                  AS count_rows,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
             ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                                   AS rn_tables,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name)
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
        ) AS count_tables
    FROM
        all_constraints   cons,
        all_cons_columns  cols,
        all_tables        tab,
        all_tab_columns   tab_col
    WHERE
            cols.table_name = tab.table_name
        AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
        AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
        AND cons.owner = cols.owner
        AND tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'
        AND cols.position = 1
        and tab_col.table_name = cols.table_name 
        and cols.column_name = tab_col.column_name
    ORDER BY
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,primary_key;
--------------CURSOR----ORA2----------------------
    CURSOR get_tables_2 IS
SELECT
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,
        cols.column_name as primary_key,
     --   nvl(num_rows, - 1)                  AS count_rows,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
             ORDER BY cols.table_name
        )                                   AS rn_tables,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name)
        OVER(PARTITION BY cons.owner
        ) AS count_tables
    FROM
        all_constraints@INST2   cons,
        all_cons_columns@INST2   cols,
        all_tables@INST2         tab,
        all_tab_columns@INST2    tab_col
    WHERE
            cols.table_name = tab.table_name
        AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
        AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
        AND cons.owner = cols.owner
        AND tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'
        AND cols.position = 1
        and tab_col.table_name = cols.table_name 
        and cols.column_name = tab_col.column_name
    ORDER BY
        cons.owner,
        cols.table_name,primary_key;
BEGIN
---------------SQL---ORA1----------------------
    OPEN get_tables_1;
    LOOP
        FETCH get_tables_1 INTO
            v_1_owner,
            v_1_table_name,
            v_1_column_name,
         --   v_1_count_real_rows,
            v_1_rn_tables,
            v_1_count_tables;
        EXIT WHEN get_tables_1%notfound;
         -- dbms_output.put_line('Tabelle ' || v_1_owner ||' ' || v_1_table_name||' ' || v_1_column_name||' ' || v_1_count_real_rows  ); 

sql_stmt_1 := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,'
                || 'max(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_1_column_name, false) || ') as max_primary_key, '
                || 'min(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_1_column_name, false) || ') as min_primary_key, '
                || 'SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                         || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_1_column_name, false)
                         || ',''^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$'') '
                         || 'THEN to_number(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_1_column_name, false) || ') '
                         || 'ELSE 0 '
                         || 'END'
                || ') as sum_primary_key FROM '
            || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_1_owner, FALSE)
                     || '.'
                     || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_1_table_name, FALSE);
        --dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt_1);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt_1
        INTO
            v_1_count_rows,
            v_1_max_primary_key,
            v_1_min_primary_key,
            v_1_sum_primary_key
           ;
----------------SQL--ORA2----------------------
     
             OPEN get_tables_2;
             loop
        FETCH get_tables_2 INTO
            v_2_owner,
            v_2_table_name,
            v_2_column_name,
          --  v_2_count_real_rows,
            v_2_rn_tables,
            v_2_count_tables;
        EXIT WHEN get_tables_2%notfound;
         -- dbms_output.put_line('Tabelle ' || v_2_owner ||' ' || v_2_table_name||' ' || v_2_column_name||' ' || v_2_count_real_rows  ); 
sql_stmt_2 := 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,'
                || 'max(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_2_column_name, false) || ') as max_primary_key, '
                || 'min(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_2_column_name, false) || ') as min_primary_key, '
                || 'SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                         || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_2_column_name, false)
                         || ',''^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$'') '
                         || 'THEN to_number(' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_2_column_name, false) || ') '
                         || 'ELSE 0 '
                         || 'END'
                || ') as sum_primary_key FROM '
            || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_2_owner, FALSE)
                     || '.'
                     || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_2_table_name, FALSE);
        --dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt_2);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt_2
        INTO
            v_2_count_rows,
            v_2_max_primary_key,
            v_2_min_primary_key,
            v_2_sum_primary_key
           ;
           
               v_count_rows_diff := v_1_count_rows - v_2_count_rows;
        IF v_count_rows_diff <> 0 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(v_1_rn_tables
                                 || ' out of '
                                 || v_1_count_tables
                                 || ' Tabelle: '
                                 || v_1_owner 
                                 || '.'
                                 || v_1_table_name
                                 || ' MaxPimaryKey: '
                                 || v_1_max_primary_key || ' / ' || v_2_max_primary_key
                                 || '; MinPimaryKey: '
                                 || v_1_min_primary_key  || ' / ' || v_2_min_primary_key
                                 || '; SumPimaryKey: '
                                 || v_1_sum_primary_key || ' / ' || v_2_sum_primary_key
                                 || '; Anzahl Datensätze: '
                                 || v_1_count_rows || ' / ' || v_2_count_rows
                                 || '; Differenz: '
                                 || v_count_rows_diff);
        END IF;
         end loop;
    CLOSE get_tables_2;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE get_tables_1;
END;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your sample tables (as DDL statements we can copy-paste and execute); the current output for those tables; and the expected output for those tables.

Answer (score 0):

> I get cartesian product, so each line of the one cursor is joined to all results from the other cursor one after another.

In that case, don't use nested loops:

```sql
BEGIN
  OPEN get_tables_1;
  LOOP
    -- ...
    OPEN get_tables_2;
    LOOP
      -- ...
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Start the second loop after the previous has finished:

```sql
BEGIN
  OPEN get_tables_1;
  LOOP
    -- ...
  END LOOP;

  OPEN get_tables_2;
  LOOP
    -- ...
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

> I want to compare the meta data for both instances: 1. Number of tables 2. Max/Min/Sum of the primary key For those tables where above stats are differing in both instances display the states otherwise hide.

Open both cursors and only use 1 loop to go through the values in order:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_owner1      VARCHAR2(30);
  v_table_name1 VARCHAR2(30);
  v_owner2      VARCHAR2(30);
  v_table_name2 VARCHAR2(30);
  v_fetch1      BOOLEAN;
  v_fetch2      BOOLEAN;

  CURSOR get_tables_1 IS
    SELECT owner, table_name
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  source = 'A'
    ORDER BY owner, table_name;

  CURSOR get_tables_2 IS
    SELECT owner, table_name
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  source = 'B'
    ORDER BY owner, table_name;
BEGIN
  OPEN get_tables_1;
  OPEN get_tables_2;

  FETCH get_tables_1 INTO v_owner1, v_table_name1; -- include stats as needed
  FETCH get_tables_2 INTO v_owner2, v_table_name2; -- include stats as needed
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN get_tables_1%NOTFOUND AND get_tables_2%NOTFOUND;
    v_fetch1 := get_tables_2%NOTFOUND
                OR v_owner1 < v_owner2
                OR v_owner1 = v_owner2 AND v_table_name1 <= v_table_name2;

    v_fetch2 := get_tables_1%NOTFOUND
                OR v_owner2 < v_owner1
                OR v_owner2 = v_owner1 AND v_table_name2 <= v_table_name1;

    IF v_fetch1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        '1: ' || v_owner1 || '.' || v_table_name1  -- include stats as needed
      );
      FETCH get_tables_1 INTO v_owner1, v_table_name1;
    END IF;

    IF v_fetch2 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        '2: ' || v_owner2 || '.' || v_table_name2  -- include stats as needed
      );
      FETCH get_tables_2 INTO v_owner2, v_table_name2;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (source, owner, table_name) AS
SELECT 'A', 'OWNER1', 'TABLE1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'OWNER1', 'TABLE2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'OWNER1', 'TABLE3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'OWNER2', 'TABLE1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'OWNER2', 'TABLE3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'OWNER1', 'TABLE1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'OWNER1', 'TABLE3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'OWNER2', 'TABLE1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'OWNER2', 'TABLE2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'OWNER3', 'TABLE3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs the tables one-by-one in order of owner and table name with the rows from the cursors interleaved:

```
1: OWNER1.TABLE1
2: OWNER1.TABLE1
1: OWNER1.TABLE2
1: OWNER1.TABLE3
2: OWNER1.TABLE3
1: OWNER2.TABLE1
2: OWNER2.TABLE1
2: OWNER2.TABLE2
1: OWNER2.TABLE3
1: OWNER2.TABLE3
2: OWNER3.TABLE3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8sOPwIyW)

Comment: thanks, but in above example I get only the last table from the first instance joined with all tables from second instance. Anyway the question is: How can I utilize the results from two cursors and calculate/create new values based on them?

Comment: @kirilb It is very difficult for us to understand what you want. As I commented on your question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77941454/1509264) your question and provide a [MRE] and explain: what is wrong with your current output; what the output should be; what the logic should be to generate that output (in English we can easily comprehend, not as code); and your sample data that generates that output. Help us to help you by providing a complete question (rather than a wall of code and no way of understanding what is "wrong" nor what "right" looks like).

Comment: ok, let me put it that way:
I have 2x oracle instances, I want to compare the meta data for both instances: 
1. Number of tables 
2. Max/Min/Sum of the primary key.
For those tables where above stats are differing in both instances display the states otherwise hide. Is that a good description what I want?

Comment: @kirilb Please read what a [MRE] is and when you ask a question actually provide a complete [MRE]. Your question could be so much simpler as you do not need to include all the parts about statistics and can just ask "How can I read from two cursors and output the results from both in order?" and then provide the sample data to populate the cursor and details of the expected output. I've included something appropriate in an update to the answer but that is something **YOU** should be doing because then you will improve your questions and have a better chance of getting a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you can do this in a single SQL statement (although I can't guarantee performance will be great!):

```
WITH remote_cols AS (SELECT cons.owner,
                            cols.table_name,
                            cols.column_name AS primary_key,
                            --   nvl(num_rows, - 1)                  AS count_rows,
                            row_number() over(PARTITION BY cons.owner ORDER BY cols.table_name) AS rn_tables,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name) over(PARTITION BY cons.owner) AS count_tables,
                            dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,'
                                                       || 'max(' || cols.column_name || ') as max_primary_key, '
                                                       || 'min(' || cols.column_name || ') as min_primary_key, '
                                                       || 'SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                                                                || cols.column_name
                                                                || ',''^[+-]?\d*/.?\d+$'') '
                                                                || 'THEN to_number(' || cols.column_name || ') '
                                                                || 'ELSE 0 '
                                                                || 'END'
                                                       || ') as sum_primary_key '
                                                || 'FROM   ' || cols.owner || '.'  || cols.table_name || '@INST2') xmldata
                     FROM   all_tables@INST2 tab
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns@INST2) tab_col ON tab.owner = tab_col.owner AND tab.table_name = tab_col.table_name
                            INNER JOIN all_cons_columns@INST2 cols ON tab_col.owner = cols.owner AND tab_col.table_name = cols.table_name AND cols.column_name = tab_col.column_name
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name FROM all_constraints@INST2 WHERE constraint_type = 'P')  cons ON cols.owner = cons.owner AND cons.table_name = cols.table_name AND cols.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name AND cols.position = 1
                     WHERE  tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'),
      remote_qry AS (SELECT rc.owner
                            rc.table_name,
                            rc.primary_key,
                            rc.rn_tables,
                            rc.count_tables,
                            xr.count_rows,
                            xr.max_primary_key,
                            xr.min_primary_key,
                            xr.sum_primary_key
                     FROM   remote_cols rc
                            CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING rc.xmldata
                                                COLUMNS  count_rows NUMBER PATH 'COUNT_ROWS',
                                                         max_primary_key VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'MAX_PRIMARY_KEY',
                                                         min_primary_key VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'MIN_PRIMARY_KEY',
                                                         sum_primary_key NUMBER PATH 'SUM_PRIMARY_KEY') xr)
      local_cols AS (SELECT cons.owner,
                            cols.table_name,
                            cols.column_name AS primary_key,
                            --   nvl(num_rows, - 1)                  AS count_rows,
                            row_number() over(PARTITION BY cons.owner ORDER BY cols.table_name) AS rn_tables,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT cols.table_name) over(PARTITION BY cons.owner) AS count_tables,
                            dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows,'
                                                       || 'max(' || cols.column_name || ') as max_primary_key, '
                                                       || 'min(' || cols.column_name || ') as min_primary_key, '
                                                       || 'SUM( CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('
                                                                || cols.column_name
                                                                || ',''^[+-]?\d*/.?\d+$'') '
                                                                || 'THEN to_number(' || cols.column_name || ') '
                                                                || 'ELSE 0 '
                                                                || 'END'
                                                       || ') as sum_primary_key '
                                                || 'FROM   ' || cols.owner || '.'  || cols.table_name || '@INST2') xmldata
                     FROM   all_tables@INST2 tab
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns@INST2) tab_col ON tab.owner = tab_col.owner AND tab.table_name = tab_col.table_name
                            INNER JOIN all_cons_columns@INST2 cols ON tab_col.owner = cols.owner AND tab_col.table_name = cols.table_name AND cols.column_name = tab_col.column_name
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name FROM all_constraints@INST2 WHERE constraint_type = 'P')  cons ON cols.owner = cons.owner AND cons.table_name = cols.table_name AND cols.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name AND cols.position = 1
                     WHERE  tab.table_name NOT LIKE '%_MV'),
       local_qry AS (SELECT lc.owner
                            lc.table_name,
                            lc.primary_key,
                            lc.rn_tables,
                            lc.count_tables,
                            lc.count_rows,
                            xl.max_primary_key,
                            xl.min_primary_key,
                            xl.sum_primary_key
                     FROM   local_cols lc
                            CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING rcl.xmldata
                                                COLUMNS  count_rows NUMBER PATH 'COUNT_ROWS',
                                                         max_primary_key VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'MAX_PRIMARY_KEY',
                                                         min_primary_key VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'MIN_PRIMARY_KEY',
                                                         sum_primary_key NUMBER PATH 'SUM_PRIMARY_KEY') xl)
SELECT COALESCE(lcl.owner, rmt.owner) owner,
       COALESCE(lcl.table_name, rmt.table_name) table_name,
       lcl.primary_key local_primary_key,
       rmt.primary_key remote_primary_key,
       lcl.rn_tables local_rn_tables,
       rmt.rn_tables remote_rn_tables,
       lcl.count_tables local_count_tables,
       rmt.count_tables remote_count_tables,
       lcl.count_rows local_count_rows,
       rmt.count_rows remote_count_rows,
       lcl.max_primary_key local_max_primary_key,
       rmt.max_primary_key remote_max_primary_key,
       lcl.min_primary_key local_min_primary_key,
       rmt.min_primary_key remote_min_primary_key,
       lcl.sum_primary_key local_sum_primary_key,
       rmt.sum_primary_key remote_sum_primary_key
FROM   local_qry lcl
       FULL OUTER JOIN remote_qry rmt ON lcl.owner = rmt.owner AND lcl.table_name = rmt.table_name;
```

Note that I've removed the assertions from the dynamic query part, since we're using the metadata views, rather than user input, so it's pretty safe to assume they're already valid identifiers. The risk of SQL injection is pretty low - if you're really worried that someone has updated the database metadata to add in SQL injection comments, you've waaaaay bigger problems on your hands than not catering for it in this particular query!

Also, the above query is untested; you'll have to amend it as appropriate if it doesn't quite fit your needs. For example, you may wish to add predicates to the final query to only return rows that have a difference in the columns, or you may want to add a column and use a case statement to report if the values are the same or not, etc